# HIVEQL - Calculating weighted average with NULL values - without using Coalesce

Tags: hive, hiveql, weighted-average

**Solved - sanitized data using below logic**

`case when total_score_a IS NULL then 0 else unique_users_a end as unique_users_a`

I'm looking to create a weighted average for a number of values based on user count - the issue is some entries may have null for value. Table example below:

| id | value_a | value_b | value_c | value_d | user_count_a | user_count_b | user_count_c | user_count_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | NULL | 4 | NULL | 10 | NULL | 30 | NULL |
| 2 | 9 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 33 | 30 | 22 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | 3 | NULL | 2 | 42 | 22 | NULL | 12 |

I need to coalesce the columns else my additions and multiplications do not function. This of course changes the NULLS to 0 - however this then impacts the overall weighting. Let me give an example using the table above:

**for ID: 3 - it has a NULL for Value_A, however the corresponding user_count_a has a value. Therefore if we coalesce and change ID 3's Value A to 0, it will be included (wrongly) in the weighting calculation. Essentially what I want to do is skip over NULL values even if there is a corresponding user_count value. The reason for this is values a,b,c & d in this table represent user feedback. If it's NULL it means no feedback was given, therefore even though we have user_count, it would be incorrect to include it in the weighting as a 0**

Here's my current query:

```
select
id,
total_value_a,
user_count_a,
total_value_b,
user_count_b,
total_value_c,
user_count_c,
total_value_d,
user_count_d,
(total_wgt_user_calc/sum_of_users) as user_weighted_score,
hour
from(
  select
  id,
  total_value_a,
  user_count_a,
  total_value_b,
  user_count_b,
  total_value_c,
  user_count_c,
  total_value_d,
  user_count_d,
  (a_wgt_user_calc + b_wgt_user_calc + c_wgt_user_calc + d_wgt_user_calc) as total_wgt_user_calc,
  sum_of_users,
  hour
  from(
    select
    id,
    user_count_a,
    total_value_a,
    (total_value_a * user_count_a) as a_wgt_user_calc,
    user_count_b,
    total_value_b,
    (total_value_b * user_count_b) as b_wgt_user_calc,
    user_count_c,
    total_value_c,
    (total_value_c * user_count_c) as c_wgt_user_calc,
    user_count_d,
    total_value_d,
    (total_value_d * user_count_d) as d_wgt_user_calc,
    (user_count_a + user_count_b + user_count_c + user_count_d) as sum_of_users,
    hour
    from(
      select
      id,
      coalesce(user_count_a, 0) as user_count_a,
      coalesce(total_value_a, 0) as total_value_a,
      coalesce(user_count_b, 0) as user_count_b,
      coalesce(total_value_b, 0) as total_value_b,
      coalesce(user_count_c, 0) as user_count_c,
      coalesce(total_value_c, 0) as total_value_c,
      coalesce(user_count_d, 0) as user_count_d,
      coalesce(total_value_d, 0) as total_value_d,
      hour
      from overall_data)j)o)i;
```

I fully appreciate additions and multiplications performed in this way within HIVE is far from ideal. However even when using SUM in this way as some have suggested:

```
SUM((a_wgt_user_calc) + SUM(b_wgt_user_calc) + SUM(c_wgt_user_calc) + SUM(d_wgt_user_calc)) as total_wgt_user_calc
```

I still end up with all NULLS if coalesce isn't utilised. **I perhaps could use a case statement with IS NULL but wouldn't know the exact structure for this**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

TLDR: Currently using coalesce to allow additions and multiplications to function. This has the unintended affect of including weighting values which shouldn't be included. Need to find a way to have the calculations function without coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert this table to a better format?

```
create table user_data as select id, value, user_count, value_type from 
   (select 
      id, 
      value_a as value, 
      user_count_a as user_count, 
      'A' as value_type 
    where 
      value_a is not NULL) 
UNION
    (select 
      id, 
      value_b as value, 
      user_count_b as user_count, 
      'A' as value_type 
    where 
      value_b is not NULL) 
UNION ...
```

This would enable you to ask aggregate questions of the data that might be easier to work with.  The data won't be in 1 row but it does avoid the case statement. It likely will make the data easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your response, because of the way the IDs are required in this case - there will always be NULLs as we require a composite table with one row per ID with data from each category. So for one ID we'll have data for category A but not B for example. I've found a workaround by sanitizing the data before going into the subsequent queries.